# Include system username in helm charts in helm version 2.14.1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm version 2.14.1. I have created helm charts for an application that will be deployed by users to test their code on kubernetes cluster. I want to add labels for username values, so I can retrieve deployments by users (deployments by user labels). Is there a way to include system username in helm charts just like we do in Java with `System.getProperty("user.name")`. My helm template is like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}--{{ Release.name }}
  labels:
    application: {{ include "common.name" . }}
    branch: "{{ Release.name }}"
    username: "{{ System.user.name }}"   # need to fetch the logged in user from system here
spec:
...
```

Is there a standard way to achieve this or is there anyway I can allow users to input there usernames from command line while using `helm install` or `helm template` commands?

EDIT:
Although, the `--set` works for me in setting the values for my chart, I also need to set the same value in the dependencies. Something like this:

values.yaml

```
username: "" 

dependency1:
 username: {{ .Values.username }} 

dependency2:
 username: {{ .Values.username }}

...
```

Of course the above implementation doesn't work. I need to reference the set value in the dependencies as well

Comment: You can always use the `--set` option

Comment: @MichaelAlbers as in `helm template --set username=<username>`?

Comment: Assuming `username` is in your values.yaml, then yes. In Bash you could then do `helm template ... --set username=$USER`

Comment: In my day job, every user has their own Kubernetes namespace, and we use RBAC controls to limit users to their own namespace.  That should achieve the higher-level goal (a cluster admin can `kubectl get deployments -n dmaze`) and is automatic and enforceable.

Comment: @AvdhutMankavale Does it solve your issue?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Thanks for the answer. Although, the `--set` works for me in setting the values for my chart, I also need to set the same value in the dependencies. Please check my edit to the post above for the mock implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this. Thanks for help @MichaelAlbers and @WytrzymałyWiktor. So the solution is as below.

```
helm template path/to/chart --set global.username=username
```

And then in all the templates refer to this value as `{{ .Values.global.username }}`. This works for any dependency chart as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer based on the comments and posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

You can use the `helm template` command with a `--set` option:

```
--set stringArray              set values on the command line (can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1=val1,key2=val2)
--set-file stringArray         set values from respective files specified via the command line (can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1=path1,key2=path2)
--set-string stringArray       set STRING values on the command line (can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1=val1,key2=val2)
```

The `--set` parameters have the highest precedence among other methods of passing values into the charts. It means that by default values come from the `values.yaml` which can be overridden by a parent chart's `values.yaml`, which can in turn be overridden by a user-supplied values file, which can in turn be overridden by `--set` parameters.

You can check more details and examples in the [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/).